# Injecting java map values through xml spring

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have a map defined inside a java class:

```
public void config{
       private Map<String, String> valueMap = Collections.emptyMap();
}
```

I need to populate this map in spring xml:

```
 <property name="configurations">
       <util:properties id="values" location="values.xml"/>
    </property>
  <property name="valueMap" ref="values">                                         
</property>
```

Values.xml:

```
<map>
    <entry key="Key1" value="Value1"/>
    <entry key="Key2" value="Value2"/>
</map>
```

The above method does not work. Please help me as to how I should proceed.

Comment: 1st thing, you are using Collections.emptyMap(); not dependency injection on this field, so spring does not touch it.

Comment: But when i populate the map statically in xml, it is getting injected.                            <property name="valueMap"">                                                         <map>
    <entry key="Key1" value="Value1"/>
    <entry key="Key2" value="Value2"/>
</map></property>                                                                           The above code works.

Comment: so probably setter injection is used. Remove Collections.emptyMap(); then. Your <map> needs an id - <map id="values"> + be sure that values.xml name is lower-space.

Comment: Didnt work. Is there a way to read the values from a properties file instead of xml? How should i give the key value pairs in that case?